# DefaultIfEmpty is ignored

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to figure out why this LINQ query (C#) doesn't work as expected:

```
// If the user receives 3 salaries, take the first, if not, show as 100 
var salary = populationData
             .Select(
                 x => x.AdultData?
                       .TaxPayerData?
                       .Where(x => x.Salary.Count == 3)
                       .Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault()
             )
             .DefaultIfEmpty(100)
             .ToList();
```

PS I corrected the names of the properties, they were misleading, sorry.

Suppose for some people `IsAdult = false` and `TaxPayer = null`, for those people I need `DefaultIfEmpty = 100`, or any other value I choose, but not `null`. Currently, my result comes as `null`.
Any thoughts, please?

Comment: It doesn't throw ArgumentNullException, I think it's because of the ?.Where. ... and I think the FirstOrDefault overrides my DefaultIfEmpty but using just First doesn't let the program compile

Comment: `DefaultIfEmpty` means if the preceding query results in an empty result then return a result with the single default value.  Since all you have before is a `Select` it's only going to default if `populationData` is empty.

Comment: Can you show your `populationData` class ?

Comment: If `IsAdult` is a boolean (based on _Suppose for some people IsAdult = false_) then how does `x.IsAdult?.TaxPayer` even compile?

Comment: In a moment, I will edit my question, sorry about that.

Comment: Without knowing what all the types are, I'm guessing you need a `?? 100` after the `FirstOrDefault`.  But I don't think `DefaultIfEmpty` is what you're looking for.

Comment: It worked like this, thank you juharr! I will update the question, if you would like to  you can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
// If the user receives 3 salaries, take the first, if not, show as 100 
var salary = populationData
             .Select(
                 x => {
                       var result = x.AdultData?
                       .TaxPayerData?
                       .Where(x => x.Salary.Count == 3)
                       .Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault()
                       return result ?? 100;}
             )
             .ToList();
```